# Yii2 - Capture paramether from router in beforeAction

Tags: yii, routes, yii2

Is there a way to capture parameter from router in the beforeAction, so it could be use by all functions in controller?

I have this router:

```
'http://<user:\w+>.' . $domain . '/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

I want to use  as ID in all functions in controller, and make it available without injecting it into the function? Is this possible?

Comment: In your example the *user* is the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

A raw solution can be intercept the `$params` array inside the `bindActionParams`:

```
class ParamController extends Controller {
   public $user;

    public function bindActionParams($action, $params)
    {
        if(isset($params['user'])){
            // may be some business based on $this or $action
            $this->user = $params['user'];
        }
        return parent::bindActionParams($action, $params); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

Of course you need to *extends* all your controllers from `ParamsController`.